# Bug in how new user status is calculated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-users

These, I suppose, are relatively exceptional circumstances<sup>1</sup> that the designers of the stackexchange network didn't necessarily think about, but it seems that there is a bug in the calculation of new user status.

In the review queue for Late Answers, I was just asked to review the late answer from a new user currently going by the name [Weirdstress Function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19356/weirdstress-function).

[image]

As we all know, Weirdstress Function is not a new user. What, if anything, should be done about this? Is this status by design?

---

1. For anyone who doesn't know, the exceptional circumstances are that Weirdstress Function spends all reputation in awarding bounties. From Weirdstress Function's "About Me":

> I distribute my rep in bounties as spending money for my & your pleasure is more meaningful than saving money in a bank & abandoning it unused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the purpose of pretty much everything where it matters, a "new user" is anyone who doesn't have the [remove new user restrictions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) privilege.

If you have less than 10 reputation and post an answer to a question 30 days or more after it was asked, your answer is going to end up in /review. We'll dequeue it if your reputation exceeds 100 before the post is reviewed, mostly as a sanity-check to prevent lots of old answers from flooding the queues.

We can't base this on the user's creation date or even past activity, since this would allow posts from malicious or chronically-incompetent users to go unreviewed after a while.

Comment: So the new user restrictions don't 'remember' if your rep goes above the line then drops down again? In particular, if it drops down because of awarding a bounty (rather than by getting negative rep from say downvotes)?

Comment: Correct - none of the privileges do. There's an argument to be made that bounties *shouldn't* count against your privilege level, but that's not really worth the added complexity.